# mmap and sprintf - c

Tags: c, printf, mmap

I am trying to write multiple random numbers into the memory, but I am having an issue where the for loop does not initilize the number required, and I get an output of one random integer, and random number of spaces and new lines.

```
int random_range (unsigned const low, unsigned const high) {...}

/* Create and write to a shared file for communication with another process.
 *
 * argv[1] = file name
 *
 * Note: Error processing is omitted
 */
int main (int argc, char* const argv[]) {
  int fd;
  int* file_memory;
  int numOfInt;

  numOfInt = atoi(argv[2]); //Turning 2nd argument into an integer

  /* seed the random number generator */
  srand (time (NULL));

  /* open or create a file to hold an unsigned integer  */
  fd = open (argv[1], O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

  /* write FILESIZE spaces */
  for (int i=0; i<FILESIZE; i++) write (fd, " ", 1);
  write (fd, "", 1); /* write a NULL at EOF */

  file_memory = mmap (NULL, FILESIZE, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
  close (fd);

int* temp = file_memory;

  /* write a random integer to memory-mapped area  */
for(int x=0; x<numInt; ++x){
  if(x!=(numInt-1))
    sprintf((char*) file_memory++, "%d ", random_range (-100, 100));
  else
    sprintf((char*) file_memory++, "%d\n",random_range (-100, 100));
}

file_memory = temp;
  /* release the memory  */
  munmap (file_memory, FILESIZE);
}
```

Comment: `sprintf((char *) file_memory, "%d\n", random_range (-100, 100));` You are writing to the *same* location on every loop. Need to increment `file_memory` pointer.

Comment: @kaylum I did that, but still the output are not proper

Comment: Please show your updated code. You may be updating the pointer incorrectly or some other error. Also include how you are verifying the result.

Comment: @kaylum I am verifying by ./mmap-write /tmp/afile 10 , then open it by cat /tmp/afile, updating the code now

Comment: @kaylum Updated

Comment: `file_memory++` is not correct for two reasons. 1. You are writing up to 4 character (e.g. "-100" is 4 characters). Need to use the return value of `sprintf` to know how many chars were written. 2. Don't update `file_memory` directly as you need the original value to `munmap`. Make a copy of it.

Comment: @kaylum Thank you, I forgot about the proper way to increment